# Is it right to say "Invest on"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know if it is correct to say "invest on" or "invest in" in this context: the company that I work is giving an english course to an employee, so, it is right to say that the company is investing on Joyce or investing in Joyce?

Thank you!

Comment: Also, simply googling "invest in or on" yields helpful sites, including: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-is-correct-invest-in-or-invest-on.512412/ and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208390/is-it-right-say-invest-on

Answer (score 1):

They are investing 'in' the person, in this case 'Joyce'.

You would use on differently like so:

> "I am investing on the advice I received from a friend"

'on' here is descriptive of the reason you are investing.

'in' is relating the object of the investment, in this case Joyce.